# How to make line chart with data from CPU in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, cpu-usage, android-profiler

In Android I could use profiler to have CPU line chart or something similar to Android chart like in below picture.

[image: Android CPU Chart]

I have tried this CPU Profiler, but there is no such data. How to download such data to even make it in Excel? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for how the CPU Profiler collects these data, here are the source code: [cpu_usage_sampler.h](https://cs.android.com/android-studio/platform/tools/base/+/mirror-goog-studio-main:profiler/native/perfd/cpu/cpu_usage_sampler.h) and [cpu_usage_sampler.cc](https://cs.android.com/android-studio/platform/tools/base/+/mirror-goog-studio-main:profiler/native/perfd/cpu/cpu_usage_sampler.cc). These code runs in a native process on Android devices as the shell user, so it may not be feasible to port them to run as a regular app.